# Nifi org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException

Tags: apache, hadoop, hive, apache-nifi

I have Nifi 1.4.0 and Hive 2.3.0 . Metastore Service is running fine but some some reason Nifi can't execute PutHiveStreaming Processor.

Following is the full stack. any idea on this?

```
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.lambda$onHiveRecordsError$1(PutHiveStreaming.java:527)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming$$Lambda$392/1467727491.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.ExceptionHandler$OnError.lambda$andThen$0(ExceptionHandler.java:54)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.ExceptionHandler$OnError$$Lambda$394/2094052256.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.lambda$onHiveRecordError$2(PutHiveStreaming.java:545)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming$$Lambda$389/23901131.apply(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.ExceptionHandler.execute(ExceptionHandler.java:148)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.lambda$onTrigger$12(PutHiveStreaming.java:677)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming$$Lambda$383/664174107.process(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.read(StandardProcessSession.java:2174)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardProcessSession.read(StandardProcessSession.java:2144)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.onTrigger(PutHiveStreaming.java:631)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.lambda$onTrigger$4(PutHiveStreaming.java:555)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming$$Lambda$379/701280946.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.PartialFunctions.onTrigger(PartialFunctions.java:114)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.util.pattern.RollbackOnFailure.onTrigger(RollbackOnFailure.java:184)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.hive.PutHiveStreaming.onTrigger(PutHiveStreaming.java:555)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1119)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:147)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:128)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter$ConnectFailure: Failed connecting to EndPoint {metaStoreUri='thrift://
Caused by: org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter$TxnBatchFailure: Failed acquiring Transaction Batch from EndPoint: {m
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: null
```

Answer (score 0):

The Hive processors in Apache NiFi 1.4.0 are built against Apache NiFi 1.2.1, so are not guaranteed to work with Apache Hive 2.3.0. Also there may be incompatibilities between Apache NiFi and a vendor-specific version of Hive. For example, if you are using the Hortonworks Data Platform (HDP), it has a Hive version based on 1.2.x but is closer to 2.0. Apache NiFi's Hive processors are not compatible with HDP 2.5+, you would likely want to use the NiFi-only Hortonworks Data Flow (HDF) package. This version of NiFi is built against the HDP Hive 1.2.x version.

Having said that, none of the above solutions are guaranteed to work against Hive 2.x (whether Apache or vendor-specific), as the NiFi baseline is still 1.2.x.